# Get only the date in timestamp in mysql

Tags: mysql, date

On my database under the t_stamp columns I have the date for example

```
2013-11-26 01:24:34
```

From that same column I only want to get the date

```
2013-11-26
```

How can i do this? Thank You!

Answer (score 120, accepted):

You can use `date(t_stamp)` to get only the date part from a timestamp.

You can check the date() function [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)

> **DATE(expr)**
>
> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.
>
> mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
>           -> '2003-12-31'

Answer (score 4):

You can convert that time in Unix timestamp by using

select UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-26 01:24:34')

then convert it in the readable format in whatever format you need

select from_unixtime(UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-11-26 01:24:34'),"%Y-%m-%d");

For in detail you can visit [link](http://www.easysolutionweb.com/mysql-tutorials/mysql-unix-timestamp-and-from-unixtime)

Answer (score 2):

To get only date from timestamp in MySQL just use `DATE_FORMAT(datetime, '%Y-%m-%d')`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2013-11-26 01:24:34', '%Y-%m-%d');
> 2013-11-26
```

Answer (score -8):

```
$date= new DateTime($row['your_date']) ;  
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: THIS SNIPPET IS FOR `php` 

WHERE  THE POST ASKED FOR  
`mysql`