# MYSQL selecting date on timestamp

Tags: mysql, date

I know this question have many similar posts but I'm having a hard time finding what I truly need.

I want to get only date from timestamp which I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228731/get-only-the-date-in-timestamp-in-mysql). I tried that using the query below:

```
SELECT *, DATE('2014-04-26') FROM labor
```

Code above is working perfectly fine. But I want to know **how do I get all records including there timestamp but only extracting the date from the timestamp**

If I'm using a wrong datatype please let me know. My table structure is like this:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why did I get I minus on my post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *, DATE(last_update) FROM labor;
```

Comment: `SELECT *, DATE('last_update') test FROM labor` The `test` column from the select is null.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need

```
SELECT *, DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(last_update) FROM labor
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362874/how-to-convert-timestamp-to-datetime-in-mysql) detailing timestamp conversions.

Comment: What is the difference of this from `SELECT *, DATE('last_update') FROM labor;`?

Comment: @newbie appears that there is no real difference - I was not aware that it is possible to call DATE with giving a timestamp. The other answers are definitely better.

Answer (score 1):

You can do as

```
select 
    col1,
    col2,
    ...
    coln,
    date(last_update)
    from labor
```

`col1. col2..coln` are the column names from your table except the last_update.