# Remove the time stamps from a SQL Server query result

Tags: sql, sql-server

Could someone please help me to remove the timestamps from my query results?

My date/time column indicates the product delivery like this

```
12/14/2020 5:00:00 AM
```

I really don't care about the time of the day but I like to have my entire date mm/dd/year.

Your help is greatly appreciated in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get only the date in timestamp in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228731/get-only-the-date-in-timestamp-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you can `cast()` or `convert()` a `datetime` to a `date`:

```
convert(date, mydatetime) as mydate
```

... Where `mydatetime` is the column you want to convert.

Comment: Just out of curiosity - you're showing the `convert` - any reason you prefer this, over `CAST(mydatetime AS DATE)` ? Personally, I find the `CAST` a bit cleaner and "more obvious" - but that might just be me ..... :-)

Comment: @marc_s: I pretty much navigate randomly between both. But I think you have a good point, I might "convert" myself to consitently using `cast()`!

Answer (score 0):

If it is a date/time column, then use:

```
convert(date, col)
```

If it is a string (and it should not be):

```
left(col, 10)
```